# Delete email attachment after sending powershell

Tags: windows, powershell

I have wrote a script for automated email using powershell.

The email sends however how can i configure it so that the file that is attached is moved to another folder inside the folder it was originally located?

```
#Searches dir for list , formats 
$Attachment = Get-ChildItem -Path $dir -Filter "*$($Region.name)*" -Recurse
$AttachmentName = $Attachment.BaseName

$Subject = "$AttachmentName @ $Time"
$Body = "Please find attached the file needed for $($Region.name). 

Regards,
Me
"
#Actions Email
Send-MailMessage -From $Region.From -To $Region.To -CC $Region.Cc -Subject $Subject -Body $Body -SmtpServer $SMTPServer -Attachments $Attachment.FullName
Move-Item Get-ChildItem -Path $dir -Filter "*$($Region.name)*" -Recurse "C:\Users\users\Desktop\MissingImageLists\OldLists"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove your `Move-Item` command and replace it with:

```
$Attachment | Move-Item -Destination "$dir\subfolder"
```